# Association vs Pattern Matching: which one is better for data storage?

Tags: pattern-matching, associations

Say I have a few key-value pairs. I can store them with `Association` as

```
food = <|"apple" -> "fruit", "pork" -> "meat"|>
```

or pattern matching as

```
food["apple"] = "fruit"
food["pork"] = "meat"
```

Generally, which one is considered a better practice? Especially, which one is faster?

Comment: I'd venture that using an association is much better in this context: everything is saved as OwnValue of a single object; data organization, storage and retrieval is the whole point of Associations. Regarding the timing, you could just try to measure it yourself in your own application as well.

Comment: I tried it and it looks like both methods are approximately equally efficient.